# How to consider JSON structure when write into file

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to save the entities in our program into .json files to get a better connection between backend and our Angular frontend. For this, I wrote some tests and during the execution, the structure is saved in the files as desired.

The structure is sampled by

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
try{
    ObjectWriter writer = objectMapper.wrtier(new DefaultPrettyPrinter()); 
    String result = objectMapper.writerWirthDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(new OurObject()); 
    writer.writerValue(new File("path"), result);
}
```

What I got

```
"{\r\n \"firstProp\": something,\r\n \"secondProp\": anything,\r\n...
```

But I want, that the file contains the classical JSON structure to make it better readable, this means:

```
{
     "firstProp": something,
     "secondProp": anything,
...
```

What can I do, to write it in the desired JSON structure?

Thanks for any help

Matthias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're double-encoding the json string

Remove `writeValueAsString` and try to directly use `writer.writerValue(file, object)`

But if you're emitting this from a Java backend, it's typically best practice to serve it from an HTTP request, not as a file to any front-end

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, it worked :). You are right we have done this before, but the main advantage is, that our backend has not to be available to run the frontend test this allows unit tests and avoid end-to-end tests which are too expensive at the moment.